# viaRemember not work - laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel

**Auth :: attempt works perfect**, but when you pass the second parameter "true" apparently does not care or does not recover with viaRemember

viaRemember fails to work, check this

**controller User**

```
`$`userdata = array(
    'email'     => trim(Input::get('username')),
    'password'  => trim(Input::get('password'))
);

if(Auth::attempt(`$`userdata, true)){
    return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
}
```

**view 'dashboard', always show 777**

```
@if (Auth::viaRemember())
    {{666}}
@else
    {{777}}
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I have hit the same obstacle, so looking into the code one can see that `viaRemember` is not meant to be used as a function to check if the user was logged into the system in one of all the ways a user can be logged in.

'viaRemember' is meant to check if a user was logged into the system specifically via the `viaRemember' cookie.

From what I gather, authentication of user is remembered in two ways:

1. a `via remember` cookie.

   The cookie value is compared to the `via remember` field in the users table.
2. a session cookie.

   The cookie value is used in the server to get the session from the
   session store. On the session object from the store there is data attached. One of the
   data items is the user id connected to the session. The first time
   the session was created, the system attached the user id to the data
   of the season.

In `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` class:

```
public function user()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) return;

    // If we have already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
    // return it back immediately. We do not want to pull the user data every
    // request into the method because that would tremendously slow an app.
    if ( ! is_null($this->user))
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());

    // First we will try to load the user using the identifier in the session if
    // one exists. Otherwise we will check for a "remember me" cookie in this
    // request, and if one exists, attempt to retrieve the user using that.
    $user = null;

    if ( ! is_null($id))
    {
        $user = $this->provider->retrieveByID($id);
    }

    // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
    // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
    // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
    $recaller = $this->getRecaller();

    if (is_null($user) && ! is_null($recaller))
    {
        $user = $this->getUserByRecaller($recaller);
    }

    return $this->user = $user;
}
```

The `getUserByRecaller` function is called only if the session cookie authentication did not work.

The `viaRemember` flag is only set in the `getUserByRecaller` function. The `viaRemember` method is only a simple getter method.

```
    public function viaRemember()
{
    return $this->viaRemember;
}
```

So in the end, we can use `Auth::check()` that does make all the checks including the `viaRemember` check. It calls the `user()` function in the Guard class.

It seems also the `viaRemember` is only an indicator. You need to do a type of `Auth::check()` the will get the process of authentication started and so the user() function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is on Laravel 4.0 but `viaRemember()` is added in Laravel 4.1! So that's expected.

Comment: Guys, I'm using 4.1.22. But it is not working. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

in `config\session.php` file change the `'expire_on_close' = false` to `true` and once you close restart your browser, it must be ok.