# Auth::viaRemember() doesnot work (means always return false even after successful login) in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.4

I make use of `php artisan make:auth` in laravel 5.4, as we know laravel default login only supports email so, I put `login()` in AuthController like below (login working)-

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $remember = ($request->input('remember')=='1')?true:false;
    // this will remember the user as given in laravel documentation.
    if (Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->password],$remember)) {
        return redirect()->intended('admin');
    } 

    elseif (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->password],$remember)) {

            return redirect()->intended('admin'); 
    } 


    else {
        return redirect('/login')->with(['error'=>'Invalid user name and password'])
                                 ->withInput();

    }
}
```

Now, whenever session expired simply typing url should redirect to admin/dashboard, But couldnot do so... By default it redirects to login page.

I put `Auth::viaRemember()` in constructor of AuthContoller class before checking for middleware like below-

```
public function __construct()
{
    // login with  remember me before checking whether its logged in or not
    Auth::viaRemember();
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

What i follow in stack overflow -

[Via Remember me always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885982/via-remember-me-always-return-false) -this link is similar to mine

[viaRemember not work - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269223/viaremember-not-work-laravel)

[Laravel 5 viaRemember() always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439494/laravel-5-viaremember-always-false)

[Laravel: Implement Auth::viaRemember() across the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406753/laravel-implement-authviaremember-across-the-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
     // dd($request->has('remember'));
    $remember =$request->has('remember');
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $remember
    );
}
```

use this in AuthenticateUsers.php it worked for me

Comment: thanks for your experience, but it did not work... now i re-install laravel 5.4, working fine ... I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct()
{
    Auth::viaRemember()
    Auth::check();
    Auth::viaRemember();
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

try this

Comment: use the edited answer once @VeshrajJoshi and do you have session.php has expire_on_close => false? and make sure to refresh your broswer using ctrl+f5 couple of times

Comment: why are we doing like this... let me check

Comment: put this code in your BaseController inside __construct function

Comment: still same problem

Comment: thanks for your answer, even though it's did not work for me. But we need to appreciate the effort being made to solve problem of others. I did ... +10 points.