# Laravel 7 - How to make 'Remember me' functionality work properly?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, remember-me

I am trying to implement the remember me functionality in my web site using `Auth::viaRemember()` but it always returns a value of `false`. what causes this and how to resolve this issue?

The remeber_token generates and stores it in database fine.

Here's the things i've tried:

1. Change the the value of `'expire_on_close'` from **false** to **true** in `config/session.php`
2. Cleared the cookies and google chrome browser cache then restarted my browser
3. ran the `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan route:clear`
4. Logged in with remember me checked then logged out (to see if the crendentials was saved).

Here's my `login` method code inside `LoginController.php`:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $remember = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')], $remember))
    {
        if(Auth::viaRemember())
        {
            dd("remembered successfully");
        }else{
            dd("failed to remember");
        }

        return view('home');
    }else{
        return back()->with('error','your username and password are wrong.');
    }
}
```

Here's my snippet code of `login.blade.php` file:

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
          <div class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

               <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                      {{ __('Remember Me') }}
               </label>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the login page just in case:

[image]

There's no problem in logging in and successfully redirects to the home page. The only problem is that the credentials are not showing up or the log in form does not remember the credentials logged in before with remember me checked.

Had the same problem with this post and its references/posts included: 
[Auth::viaRemember() doesnot work (means always return false even after successful login) in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403391/authviaremember-doesnot-work-means-always-return-false-even-after-successfu) but unfortunately none of the provided solution works for me..

P.S.

I am using Laravel Framework 7.14.1 and latest google chrome version as of this moment (Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: the remember me functionality has nothing to do with the login form being 'prefilled' ... that is between you and your browser ... the remember me functionality is so that after your session expires there is still a way to authenticate you without you logging in again; using the remember me cookie since the session is dead and can't be authenticated via the session... you are not logged in via the remember functionality until the session has expired and it has to now use that functionality .. if you log in by credentials you are not currently logged in `viaRemember`

Comment: no problem, also i believe you will only have `viaRemember` respond true for the first request that uses the recaller cookie, after that you are logged in again like normal and `viaRemember` won't return true